# Android View implements Runnable - is it ok, or Handler is a must?

Tags: android, multithreading, view

I would like to ask a question about android [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) drawing in a loop for games or animations.

I have done previously some game development for j2me, and I tried to implement the same drawing logic in android, just to measure performance and to experiment with the framework. My first try is with View and onDraw(). Later I'll try with SurfaceView.

So here is my question: I extended View and made the View implement Runnable, so it can start a thread to make the loop not on the UI thread. The code is working fine.

The thing that bothers me is that in the android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), it's written that it's not possible to call methods of the View from another thread without using a Handler. The docs say that I should use a handler, however my code is working without it.

Quote:

> Note: The entire view tree is single
>   threaded. You must always be on the UI
>   thread when calling any method on any
>   view. If you are doing work on other
>   threads and want to update the state
>   of a view from that thread, you should
>   use a Handler.

Here is the code of the View. Is there a reason why I should prefer using Handler instead of the code below?

Thank you very much.

```
public class DrawView extends View implements Runnable
{
    private Context mContext = null;    
    private Thread drawThread = null;
    private Drawable mIcon = null;

    public DrawView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        mIcon.draw(canvas);
    }

    public void start()
    {
        if(drawThread == null) drawThread = new Thread(this);
        drawThread.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            // updateGameState(); // move the objects (icon) to new position
            postInvalidate(); // request for drawing objects
        }
    }
}
```

---- EDIT ----

It seems that its reasonable to use the code above without using Handler, when the View is updated via [postInvalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

> Cause an invalidate of the specified
>   area to happen on a subsequent cycle
>   through the event loop. Use this to
>   invalidate the View from a non-UI
>   thread.

So it seems to me that the note in the Android Docs about View should be corrected, because Handler is not the only option to go when you want to update a View from another thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handler is not a must, you could always use `runOnUiThread()`.

However I'm not sure this behaves as you intend. To clarify: Your View must (as far as I know) be generated on and handled by the UI thread's `Looper`. Most functionality exposed by View checks for illegal cross-thread calls, because `View` is not designed to be accessible by multiple threads at once.

If you extend View, you can always call your own methods from any thread, BUT you cannot access the inherited functionality without posting something to the UI thread's message queue. If you do this with a `Handler`, by `runOnUiThread()` or by using some other thread-safe method (can't think of any right now) is up to you.

In your case, `run()` runs on it's own thread, but `postInvalidate()` will cause the redraw from the UI thread.

Comment: thank you for the answer. yes, the code above works with postInvalidate() - in the docs is also written, that it's ok to be used when you want to invalidate the view from another thread. However I saw this today :)

Comment: Could you please post a link to where you read that it's ok to call postInvalidate from another thread?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: Oh, of course ;) thanks, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

the movement is more smooth whith runnable as i get 60fps or 150 if i want compared to 30 when using handler, though i dont have more than 10 objects moving at the same time, i guess this might be device dependent and maybe android os version dependent. Motorola flipout uses 2.1. Anyway using runnable method comes from j2me games so it should be working ok and you only have to minimize your thread sleep not to run too fast. Using handler probably does that for you

Answer (score 0):

did some xperimenting and if you want to achieve more than 30fps, for example matching iphone standards 60fps you will need to use runnable as in your example without handler, when i use a handler it never goes beyond 30fps. Some say its enough but when you compare to 60 its just not the same especially for fast paced games but it will possibly drain battery quicker

Comment: I tried both methods - with handler and with runnable, and the FPS is about the same, also I make 60fps with both on Android G1. Maybe depends on the phone also. AFAIK the G1 has GPU, but Tattoo and Wildfire do not have...

Comment: Also with runnable the animation of the objects is not very smooth for some reason, while with handler it looks a lot better...

Comment: tried motorola flipout and runnable gives almost 4xfaster fps which i limit to 60 not to drain battery

Comment: do you have problems with the animation - crappy object movement? I have tried with 20 objects moving on the screen and with runnable they were NOT moving very smoothly... however with Handler the movement was (almost) perfect :) The FPS of Handler was 10-15% lower than Runnable, but was still 56-60 fps on Android G1